Are mutli-story structure slabs poured on-center?
What exactly does it mean to have a multi-storey building where each storey is 2.4 meters?
I've read a lot of descriptions of buildings that say each storey is "2.4 meters" or "3 meters", but I never understand what they mean.
Typically, if a building has "2.4 meter" stories, does that mean that the spacing between the slabs on-center of each slab is 2.4 meters? Or does it mean that there is exactly 2.4 meters of clearance between the top of one slab and the bottom of the slab above it?

Case of refer to drawing.

@SolarMike I'm the one doing the drawing. I'm asking for what is the standard, most-common case. And what is most supported/referenced by building codes.

Multi-story buildings ( and any other building for that matter) are designed according to the code governing such Buildings.
For example, in California, The minimum height of ceilings shall be 8 feet (2438 mm). Exception: Closet, toilet rooms, and bathroom minimum ceiling heights shall not be less than 7 feet (2134 mm).
These are non-negotiable clear floor-to-ceiling minimums. Any mechanical ducting or plumbing False ceiling has to be added to this.
Then the slab and the story floor beams are added to this total.
Other concerns can increase this minimum height such as the incursion of structural elements like shear transfer beams or lateral bracing.
Usually the architect in coordination with their structural and mechanical, etc, consultants design the project considering all the relevant issues.
